# How to filter strings from an array excluding the longest string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get the array excluding the longest string. My code returns an empty array.

My code:

```js
const students = [
  'Andy', 'Thomas', 'Elizabeth', 'Vicky'
]
console.log(students)

const longestName = students.reduce(nameOfMaxLen)
console.log(longestName)

function nameOfMaxLen(name1, name2){
  return name1.length > name2.length ? name1 : name2;
}

const allButTheLongest = students.filter(function(name){
  name != longestName;
})
console.log(allButTheLongest)
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Does `console.log(longestName)` log the expected value in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback of your filter does not return a value.

Either use

```
const allButTheLongest = students.filter(name => name != longestName)
```

or

```
const allButTheLongest = students.filter(function(name){
  return name != longestName;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot to `return` from the callback function in the filter!

You need to return true or false so that the filter command knows whether to include the value in the filtered output or not. You did the calculation but didn't return the value. If you don't return anything it assumes `false` (i.e. filter it out).

```js
const students = [
  'Andy', 'Thomas', 'Elizabeth', 'Vicky'
]
console.log(students)

const longestName = students.reduce(nameOfMaxLen)
console.log(longestName)

function nameOfMaxLen(name1, name2){
  return name1.length > name2.length ? name1 : name2;
}

const allButTheLongest = students.filter(function(name){
  return name != longestName; //don't forge the "return" keyword!
})
console.log(allButTheLongest)
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put a `return` in front of your comparison in the filter handler function.

```js
const students = ['Andy', 'Thomas', 'Elizabeth', 'Vicky'];

const longestName = students.reduce(nameOfMaxLen)
console.log(longestName)

function nameOfMaxLen(name1, name2){
  return name1.length > name2.length ? name1 : name2;
}

const allButTheLongest = students.filter(function(name){
  return name != longestName;
})
console.log(allButTheLongest)
```

You could also do it like this:

```js
const students = ['Andy', 'Thomas', 'Elizabeth', 'Vicky', 'Alexander'];
const allButLongest=(maxlen=>students.filter(e=>e.length<maxlen)) // IIFE is defined
 (students.reduce((a,c)=>a=Math.max(c.length,a),0)) // IIFE is called with a calculated argument maxlen

console.log(allButLongest)
```

I create an IIFE (immediately invoked functional expression) in which I calculate the `maxlen` for the given array first. This value will then be used in the filtering expression. Unlike the original version, this one will filter out *several* "longest" names, if they happen to be present.